# React input flips every time i click the next input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two drop down inputs. I am having some unexplained issues with them however. When I click on the top input and select it works as expected until I select the bottom input. As soon as I select an option from the bottom selection it makes the top input reset the to the "pick an option". I am not sure how to change this behavior. Thanks for helping.

```
import "../App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { checkRef } from "./firebase";

function Interface() {
  const [choices, setChoices] = useState({
    selectValue: "Pick Reason",
    damageValue: "Pick Reason",
    submitted: true,
    default: "Pick Option",
    screen: 0,
    keys: 0,
    trackpad: 0,
    headphneJack: 0,
    battery: 0,
    other: 0
  });

  let handleCart = function(e) {
    return setChoices({ selectValue: e.target.value });
  };

  let handleDamage = function(e) {
    if (e.target.value === "Broken Screen") {
      return setChoices({

        selectValue: choices.selectValue,
        damageValue: e.target.value,
        submitted: true,
        default: "Pick Option",
        keys: 0,
        trackpad: 0,
        headphneJack: 0,
        battery: 0,
        other: 0,
        screen: +1
      });
      //
    } else if (e.target.value === "Broken Keys") {
      return setChoices({
        selectValue: choices.selectValue,
        damageValue: e.target.value,
    submitted: true,
    default: "Pick Option",
    screen: 0,
    keys: +1,
    trackpad: 0,
    headphneJack: 0,
    battery: 0,
    other: 0


      });
    } else if(e.target.value === "Won't Charge"){
        return setChoices({
            selectValue: choices.selectValue,
            damageValue: e.target.value,
            submitted: true,
            default: "Pick Option",
            screen: 0,
            keys: 0,
            trackpad: 0,
            headphneJack: 0,
            battery: +1,
            other: 0
        })
    } else if(e.target.value === "Trackpad"){
        return setChoices({
            selectValue: choices.selectValue,
            damageValue: e.target.value,
            submitted: true,
            default: "Pick Option",
            screen: 0,
            keys: 0,
            trackpad: +1,
            headphneJack: 0,
            battery: 0,
            other: 0
        })
    }
    //

    //
    else {
      return setChoices({ ...choices, damageValue: e.target.value });
    }
  };

  let buttonSub = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const item = {

      reason: choices.damageValue,
      grade: choices.selectValue,
      screen: choices.screen,
      keys: choices.keys,
      battery: choices.battery,
      trackpad: choices.trackpad
    };
    checkRef.push().set(item);
    setChoices({
    damageValue: 'hi',
      submitted: false,
      screen: 0,
      keys: 0,
      battery: 0,
      trackpad: 0
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Chromebook Deposit Form</h1>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Choose what grade you're in</label>
          <select
            className="form-control w-50 "
            id="cart"
            onChange={handleCart}
            value={choices.damageValue}
          >
            <option>{choices.default}</option>
            <option>6th Grade</option>
            <option>7th Grade</option>
            <option>8th Grade</option>
          </select>
          <hr></hr>
          <label>Select Your Reason For deposit</label>
          <select
            className="form-control w-50 "
            id="cart"
            value={choices.damageValue}
            onChange={handleDamage}
          >
            <option>{choices.default}</option>
            <option>Broken Screen</option>
            <option>Broken Keys</option>
            <option>Won't Charge</option>
            <option>Trackpad</option>
            <option>Other</option>
          </select>

          <button className="button" onClick={buttonSub}>
            Submit Information
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Interface;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem the value you are setting for the first select dropdown in the jsx. It's assigned to damageValue, but when you handle the selection on that dropdown you are setting selectValue. It is fine as long as damageValue doesn't change, that's why the problems start when you change the second dropdown, which also changes damageValue.
This should fix your problem:

```
....
<select
  className="form-control w-50 "
  id="cart"
  onChange={handleCart}
  value={choices.selectValue}
>
...
```

Comment: thanks this works but when I submit the top field does not reset

Comment: If you check the submit function, you are not resetting `selectValue` attribute value. if you add `selectValue: '',` when you call `setChoices` at the end of `buttonSub` function, it will reset.

Comment: Thank you so much I get it now!! I'm new to react! I appreciate your input!